# Add key values pair inside list into pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, dictionary

I have listA as

```
[{'index': 0,
  'keywords': ['nuclear','china','force','capabilities','pentagon','defence']},
 {'index': 1,
  'keywords': ['pakistan', 'membership', 'china', 'nsg', 'kirby', 'meets']},
 {'index': 2,
  'keywords': ['payment', 'rbi', 'applications', 'bill', 'bbpou', 'payments']}]
```

`

I want to add it into pandas column as first element into first cell. Output I'm expected as:-

```
Column_new
{'index': 0,'keywords': ['nuclear','china','force','capabilities','pentagon','defence']}
{'index': 1,'keywords': ['pakistan', 'membership', 'china', 'nsg', 'kirby', 'meets']}
{'index': 2,'keywords': ['payment', 'rbi', 'applications', 'bill', 'bbpou', 'payments']}
```

What I have done is :-

```
df = pd.DataFrame(listA,col=['Column_new'])
```

but it gives a dataframe with NaN values,

```
   Column_new
0  NaN

1  NaN

2  NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is... you got a series. Do this instead:

```
df = pd.Series(listA).to_frame('Column_new')
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

listA = [{'index': 0,
  'keywords': ['nuclear','china','force','capabilities','pentagon','defence']},
 {'index': 1,
  'keywords': ['pakistan', 'membership', 'china', 'nsg', 'kirby', 'meets']},
 {'index': 2,
  'keywords': ['payment', 'rbi', 'applications', 'bill', 'bbpou', 'payments']}]


df = pd.Series(listA).to_frame('Column_new')
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
                                          Column_new
0  {'index': 0, 'keywords': ['nuclear', 'china', ...
1  {'index': 1, 'keywords': ['pakistan', 'members...
2  {'index': 2, 'keywords': ['payment', 'rbi', 'a...
```

Comment: @James In that case you would do `df['newcolumn'] = pd.Series(listA)` or simply: `df['newcolumn'] = listA`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: can you please look into this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574485/match-keywords-in-pandas-column-with-another-list-of-elements`. I'm not getting the solution