# Match keywords in pandas column with another list of elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as:

```
word_list
['nuclear','election','usa','baseball']
['football','united','thriller']
['marvels','hollywood','spiderman']
....................
....................
....................
```

I also have multiple number of lists with categories names,something as:-

`movies=['spiderman','marvels','thriller']'`

`sports=['baseball','hockey','football']`,

`politics=['election','china','usa']` and many others categories.

All I want to match the keywords of pandas column `word_list` with my categories lists and assign the corresponding lists name in seperate column if keywords gets matched together and if any keywords not gets matched in any of the list then simply put as   `miscellaneous` So, output I'm looking for as:-

```
word_list                                          matched_list_names
['nuclear','election','usa','baseball']            politics,sports,miscellaneous
['football','united','thriller']                   sports,movies,miscellaneous               
['marvels','spiderman','hockey']                   movies,sports

....................                               .....................
....................                               .....................
....................                               ....................
```

I successfully get the match keywords as:-

```
for i in df['word_list']:
    for j in movies:
        if i in j:
           print (i)
```

but this gives me the list of matched keywords. How I get the list names and add it into pandas column?

Comment: You are asking multiple questions now. But about the relevance (1/3)*100 is actually 0.3333.... Are you not content with the current answers?

Comment: @AntonvBR I need to calculate the relevance value also. So, 0.33 can also be used. I have tried alot but my approach doesn't seems to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flatten dictionary of lists first and then lookup by `.get` with `miscellaneous` for non matched values, then convert to `set`s for unique categories and convert to `string`s by `join`:

```
movies=['spiderman','marvels','thriller']
sports=['baseball','hockey','football']
politics=['election','china','usa']
d = {'movies':movies, 'sports':sports, 'politics':politics}
d1 = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in d.items() for k in oldv}

f = lambda x: ','.join(set([d1.get(y, 'miscellaneous') for y in x]))
df['matched_list_names'] = df['word_list'].apply(f)
print (df)

                                 word_list             matched_list_names
0       [nuclear, election, usa, baseball]  politics,miscellaneous,sports
1             [football, united, thriller]    miscellaneous,sports,movies
2  [marvels, hollywood, spiderman, budget]           miscellaneous,movies
```

Similar solution with list comprehension:

```
df['matched_list_names'] = [','.join(set([d1.get(y, 'miscellaneous') for y in x])) 
                            for x in df['word_list']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Please,check the edited question.

Comment: I have added a seperate question for my query `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51589060/add-numeric-values-beside-columns-elements-in-pandas`

Comment: Need your help. Can you please take a look into this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51864822/mapping-of-pandas-column-with-column-of-another-pandas-dataframe/51864988#51864988`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you should take advantage of `O(1)` lookup from sets and dictionaries. That said, I'd set the data as (notice that *values are sets*):

```
d = dict(movies={'spiderman','marvels','thriller'},
         sports={'baseball','hockey','football'},
         politics={'election','china','usa'})
```

Then, you can `transform` your series using your custom logic

```
def f(r):
    def m(r_):
        _ = [k for (k, v) in d.items() if r_ in v]
        return _ if _ else ['Misc']
    return {item for z in [m(r_) for r_ in r] for item in z}

df.word_list.transform(f)

0    {Misc, sports, politics}
1      {Misc, sports, movies}
2              {Misc, movies}
```

For 300000 rows,

```
%timeit df.word_list.transform(f)
1.1 s ± 22.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

which is not great but doable..

Comment: I have multiple lists with large number of keywords elements. So, how do I convert it into dictionaries at once?

Comment: How do you define those lists @Mavrick ?