# How to add comma in between strings inside square brackets in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as:-

```
categories
['business $ finance'\n 'business $currency']
['entertainment $movies' 'entertainment &music']
['sports& volleyball' 'sports& football'\n 'sports$ baseball']
...............
```

All I want to convert these strings inside brackets into proper list format. Expected output as:-

```
categories
['business $ finance','business $currency']
['entertainment $movies','entertainment &music']
['sports&volleyball','sports& football','sports$ baseball']
....................
```

what I have tried so far:-

```
array_cat=[]
for i in df['categories']:
      s=i[0].split()
      array_cat.append(s)
```

## Edit

`df['categories'][0]` is something like:-

```
"['business finance#mergers & acquisitions' 'business#industries#telecom'\n 'diseases#kidney' 'gaming #offline #console#xbox'\n 'gaming #offline #playstation' 'lifestyle#shopping' 'movies#genres#drama'\n 'music#genres#hiphop/rap' 'personal finance#tools' 'technology#trending'\n 'theme#historicalsites']"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) by all values between `''`:

```
df['categories'] = df['categories'].str.findall('\'(.*?)\'')
print (df)
                                          categories
0  [business finance#mergers & acquisitions, busi...
1        [entertainment$movies, entertainment&music]
2  [sports&volleyball, sports&football, sports$ba...
```

Comment: @Mavrick - What return `print (df['categories'].iloc[1:5].to_dict())` ? Please change `1` or `5` for catch values with `\n`

Comment: @Mavrick - Can you check now?

Comment: @Mavrick - Super, your string `df['categories'][0]` help me a lot ;)

Comment: Can I just ask your help on this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51864822/matching-elements-of-pandas-column-with-column-of-another-pandas-dataframe/51869865#51869865`? It would be my pleasure.

Comment: @Mavrick - Not easy question, but I can try.

Comment: Yeah sure, Thanks :)